# export of multiple animated objects multiplies animations by objects count

Tags: animation, objects, export

I have for example 3 animated objects, with 1 animation per object (so a total of 3 animations). But when exporting (FBX), I get 3x3=9 animations, Like if all animations were distribued to all objects (it don't know which animation is linked to wich object?). That causes undesirable data.

What I Want :

- ObjectA + AnimA
- ObjectB + AnimB
- ObjectC + AnimC

But what I get :

- ObjectA + AnimA + AnimB + AnimC
- ObjectB + AnimA + AnimB + AnimC
- ObjectC + AnimA + AnimB + AnimC

**Why does it multiplies the number of animations by the number of objects?**

I Tried FBX, Collada, all options checking/unchecking, with and without NLA Strips... I always have this unexpected result.

I tried with two add-ons : FBX Bundle & Unity Tools to batch them in separate FBX files, but as always, I have all my 3 animations on each object...

It is for a real-time non-interactive animation (motion design) so I don't want to have to animate separated files because timing is very important between all objects (and I have a plenty to animate on a long timeline), also a lot of parenting within each others, so I can't separate them in multiple .blend files because of hierarchical dependencies and complex timings.

**How can I have the right amount of animations without all these duplicata ?**

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so apparently it is impossible to have multiple objects in the same FBX or DAE. I've seen demos that are cheating by merging all objects into an unique armature (so it's an illusion of multiple objects).

The solution I've taken is to have a root bone for each object at 0 0 0 (independant of the next ones) then a bone that's offseting object at right place in the scene. then copy-paste each armature/object in a new blend file. And a checking file that links all scenes of each object (I'm not enthusiast to merge all in a single gigantic armature, because animation in/out/loops are forced to be at same length, it gives no possiblity of independant looping, and no possiblity of re-use independant objects / animations).

It's the best solution I've found. If you have a better workflow for working with multiple animated objects that needs to be synced in a precise timing (like an object jumping onto another when the second one has finished it's apparition), that needs to be exported/readable/triggerable in FBX or DAE, don't hesitate to talk about it.